# Inserting few columns of Dataframe into MSSQL column and few as JSON string in another column

Tags: json, dataframe, pyodbc

I am acquiring data from multiple sources each having different set of attributes/columns. Only the columns ID and NAME are common across all data sources. My intent is to have 3 columns in MS SQL DB as below . The payload column will have JSON dumped into it, which will have additional attributes as per the source.
For discussion purpose, lets assume the payload will contain Contact Info ( Address[street,city,pin/zip, country], Phone, Email)

| ID | Name | Payload |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John |  |
| 2 | Doe |  |

The Dataframe has following columns

| ID | Name | Address | Phone | Email |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | John Addr | 1234567890 | john@email.com |
| 2 | Doe | Doe Addr | 9876543210 | doe@email.com |

If my DB columns had same structure as df, i'd just
pyodbc.executemany('Insert into table values(?,?,?,?,?), df.values.tolist())

But with my requirement to dump address , phone and email as json dump, I am kind of stuck.

How can I solutionize this please?
Thank you